# Finding an element after a specific element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector

Using jQuery selectors, how to find an element, such as `div`, immediately after another specific element? (not sibling, `next()` can not help in this situation)

Comment: [Quite related answer on an uncanny similar question for which `nextAll` was still not enough](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29084305/274502)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `nextAll()` with a filter : http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JRPGh/1/

```
<div class='start'></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class='start'></div>


$('.start').nextAll('.start:first').css('background', 'red');
```

Comment: why this code always returns null -> alert($(this).nextAll('div:first').html());

Comment: You need to post the html and your js before I can answer that. My code works so the method is correct.

Comment: Note that this method searches only for siblings afterwards, which didn't work for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for the adjacent sibling selector:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: how can i get id from $(this) for use it in adjacent-selectors?

Comment: Post some sample HTML and what element you are trying to locate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#element").find("div").text("Hello");
```

Comment: i want to use this selector in qtip2 / i think text attribute is not good for this purpose / i have many elements with tooltips (in div) after them (individually)/ i want to find tooltip div for all of them by one code - mean $(this).?????????????